# Get int value from one method to another C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, methods, int

Here is the code. I would want to use this  value of int randomIndex from SpwanArrow method in the Update method. Any ideas?

```
void SpawnArrow()
{
    //some code here        
    int randomIndex = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, arrows.Length);
    GameObject prefab = arrows[randomIndex];
    GameObject clone = Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(0.02F, 2.18F, -1), 
    Quaternion.identity);
}

void Update()
{
   if (randomIndex == 1 && (Input.GetButtonDown("a") == true))
   {
       ScoreManager.score += scoreValue;
   }
   //and so on

}
```

Comment: Make it a class level variable.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `randomIndex`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it a global variable in your class

```
int randomIndex = -1;

void SpawnArrow()
{
    //some code here        
    randomIndex = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, arrows.Length);
    GameObject prefab = arrows[randomIndex];
    GameObject clone = Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(0.02F, 2.18F, -1),
    Quaternion.identity);
}

void Update()
{
    if (randomIndex == 1 && (Input.GetButtonDown("a") == true))
    {
        ScoreManager.score += scoreValue;
    }
    //and so on

}
```

I've set it to -1 for it no to affect your update function.

Answer (score 0):

You could make randomIndex a private property. This will allow you to use it anywhere in your class.

```
private int randomIndex { get; set; }

void SpawnArrow()
{
    //some code here        
    randomIndex = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, arrows.Length);
    GameObject prefab = arrows[randomIndex];
    GameObject clone = Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(0.02F, 2.18F, -1), Quaternion.identity);
}

void Update()
{
    if (randomIndex == 1 && (Input.GetButtonDown("a") == true))
        ScoreManager.score += scoreValue;
    //and so on
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int randomIndex;   

void SpawnArrow()
    {
        //some code here        
        randomIndex = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, arrows.Length); 
        GameObject prefab = arrows[randomIndex];
        GameObject clone = Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(0.02F, 2.18F, -1), 
        Quaternion.identity);
    }

    void Update()
    {
       if (randomIndex == 1 && (Input.GetButtonDown("a") == true))
       {
           ScoreManager.score += scoreValue;
       }
       //and so on

    }
```